# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to load a data from my firebase backend but getting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function
```

my code is as below :

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const loadData = ({ commit }) => {
  console.log('getting data from server...');

  axios
    .get('data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data) {
      
        const stocks = data.stocks;
        const stockPortfolio = data.stockPortfolio;
        const funds = data.funds;

        const portfolio = {
          stockPortfolio,
          funds
        };
        commit('SET_STOCKS', stocks);
        commit('SET_PORTFOLIO', portfolio);
        console.log('Commit done ');
      }
    });
};
```

however, if I try `response.data` instead of `response.json` it works and successfully loads the data, so I am curious what the difference is and why the first one doesn't work.

Comment: You're using *axios*. Try reading the documentation for *axios* and not the documentation for *fetch*.

Comment: @skr, please mark the answer as correct if it has solved your issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the axios package, it has a specific response schema https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

```
The response for a request contains the following information.

{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
  request: {}
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant info from the link (which might be unavailable for whatever reason) in your answer.

Comment: `if (response.statusText==='OK') {return response.data}`

Answer (score 5):

With axios you don't need an extra .json() .Responses are already served as javascript object, no need to parse, simply get response and access data. You could use directly something like

```
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.config);
  });
```

Comment: Also sending `post` data to the server is different to `fetch` in that it also needs `data` instead of `body`. So both request and response go with the `data` prop.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use the Body.json() method if you are trying to resolve the promise from a `Response` stream. You may read more about it on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). One use case of doing so would be when you are making a HTTP request using the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API, whereby you will have to call `Body.json()` to return the response body.

```
let response = await fetch(url);

if (response.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
  // get the response body (the method explained below)
  let json = await response.json();
} else {
  alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
}
```

For axios, you only need to resolve the promose after making a [GET](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) request

```
axios.get(url[, config])
```

and thus, the following code below works, as the returned response body is handled within the `.then()` block when you resolve the promise.

```
axios
  .get('data.json')
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const CollectData = async () => {
    let result = await fetch('http://localhost:5400/Enquiry', {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, contact, message }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    });
    result = await result.json();
    console.log(result);
    if (result) {
      navigate("/");
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).